# Implementar token's en web services con php y json

Tags: android, mysql, webservice, tokens

He creado varios web services para consultar datos de mi base desde una aplicación en android, los web services ya funcionan, me devuelven la información y ya se muestra en la aplicación, pero quiero implementar token's como seguridad en mis consultas, pero no entiendo como puedo implementar los token's, este es un web services que uso:

```
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "mgrex";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "";

$json = array();

if(isset($_GET["empresa"]) && isset($_GET["rol"])){
    $empresa = $_GET["empresa"];
    $rol = $_GET["rol"];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    $consulta = "select * from inicio WHERE empresa = '{$empresa}' AND rol = '{$rol}'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $json['inicio'][]=$registro;    
    }

}else{
            $resultar["tituloNoticia"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["subtituloNoticia"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["imagenNoticia"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["descripcionNoticia"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["empresa"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["rol"]='No registrado';
            $json['inicio'][]=$resultar;

}
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

he estado revisando ejemplos en internet como el siguiente:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$time = time();
$key = 'my_secret_key';

$token = array(
    'iat' => $time, // Tiempo que inició el token
    'exp' => $time + (60*60), // Tiempo que expirará el token (+1 hora)
    'data' => [ // información del usuario
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Eduardo'
    ]
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);

$data = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

var_dump($data);
```

No entiendo como puedo usar este ejemplo en mi web service.

Comment: Si trabajas con login, puedes crear el token y almacenarlo temporalmente para su uso por el usuario, de esta manera lo envias con cada peticion del usuario y si es válido retornas la info, en caso de que no cierras la sesión en la app, yo también uso ese y va bastante bien

Comment: @CarlosQuintero pero el problema es que no tengo una idea clara de como se debe implementar, no entiendo como es que valida el token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para implementar Json Web Tokens (JWT). Lo primero que tienes que tener es una tabla de usuarios.

La primera parte se hace un login común y corriente. Este parte te va a responder con el un json.

La peticion debe contener lo siguiente:

- Usuario (id del usuario key)
- Contraseña (secret)

Debes de validar estos datos en tu base de datos, si estos existen debes de crear un token con los métodos de jwt.

es esto que tu tienes.

```
$token = array(
    'iat' => $time, // Tiempo que inició el token
    'exp' => $time + (60*60), // Tiempo que expirará el token (+1 hora)
    'data' => [ // información del usuario
       'id' => 1, // key 
       'name' => 'Eduardo' // secret
  ]
);
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
```

La variable jwt se convertirá en un json el cual debes de responder con algo así.

```
return $jwt;
```

Ahora cada que hagas peticiones a tu API deberás mandar en los headers este token ejemplo:

```
axios.post(
  url, 
  {
     _token: Token_jwt
  }
).then(
   res=>{ 
   }
);
```

Por ultimo, todas las peticiones que llegan a tu api deben de contener el token y este debe de ser valido. por lo tanto debes de interpretarlo.

```
<?PHP


    // obviamente tambien tienes que importar la libreria de jwt
    $key = 'Tu clave de la aplicacion';
    if(empty($_POST['_token'])){
      $data = (objetc)JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
      if($data->exp > time()){
        return abort(401);
      }
    }else{
      return abort(401);
    }




        $hostname_localhost = "localhost";
        $database_localhost = "mgrex";
        $username_localhost = "root";
        $password_localhost = "";

        $json = array();

        if(isset($_GET["empresa"]) && isset($_GET["rol"])){
            $empresa = $_GET["empresa"];
            $rol = $_GET["rol"];

            $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
            $consulta = "select * from inicio WHERE empresa = '{$empresa}' AND rol = '{$rol}'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

            while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['inicio'][]=$registro;    
            }

        }else{
                    $resultar["tituloNoticia"]='No registrado';
                    $resultar["subtituloNoticia"]='No registrado';
                    $resultar["imagenNoticia"]='No registrado';
                    $resultar["descripcionNoticia"]='No registrado';
                    $resultar["empresa"]='No registrado';
                    $resultar["rol"]='No registrado';
                    $json['inicio'][]=$resultar;

        }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);

        ?>
```

Comment: Perdón, me falto comprobar que el token efectivamente es un token valido y en caso de que no sea valido igual regresar un 401

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, ya entendí como implementar el token, también ya tengo descargado he instalado el composer y he usado este comando en la consola "composer require firebase/php-jwt" el problema que tengo ahora es que me da este error: "Uncaught Error: Class 'Firebase\JWT\JWT' not found in" al implementar el codigo de los token, sabes por que da ese error?

Comment: No lo puedes utilizar directamente porque no tienes un autoload, Incluye la clase de proyecto y luego instanciala. Seria algo así. include 'ruta del autoload donde esta jwt'; $jwt = new JWT; (o como se llame el método principal de la librería). Y después para utilizar los métodos lo haces con la variable. $jwt->decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256');